# Opencv[python] imread reads wrong color

Tags: python, opencv

My question is not duplicate of [OpenCV giving wrong color to colored images on loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39316447/opencv-giving-wrong-color-to-colored-images-on-loading?noredirect=1&lq=1)
or questions linked to above question.

I recently started learning opencv library and I am doing it in Python.

I am loading a opencv logo with white background , and doing nothing with img variable and still getting image with black background.
Please explain me , what is happening.

input image:

[image: opencv_logo.png]

output image:

[image: opencv_output_logo.png]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
img = cv2.imread('opencv_logo.png') // loaded a opencv logo with white background
cv2.imwrite('output_logo.png',img) // in output image , got it with black background
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that the transparency is not being read correctly, to do so you must use the flag `cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED`:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
img = cv2.imread('opencv_logo.png', cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED) 
cv2.imwrite('output_logo.png',img)
```