# Image changes color when using cv2 imread

Tags: python, opencv

I'm trying to read and plot an image. However, when I run my 2-line code, the plot is different than the original image. My python version is 3.8.5.

```
auxImg = (cv2.imread("train/img_0001.jpg",cv2.IMREAD_COLOR))/255
plt.imshow(auxImg)
```

I also tried without the `/255`, but it gives the same result.

Original image: [image]

Plotted image:[image: Plotted image]

Comment: Duplicate: [OpenCV giving wrong color to colored images on loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39316447/opencv-giving-wrong-color-to-colored-images-on-loading)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `cv2` module reads in images in BGR format, while the `matplotlib` module uses RGB. A simple fix would be to use the `cv2.cvtColor()` method on the image first:

```
auxImgRGB = cv2.cvtColor(auxImg, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
```

The [`COLOR_BGR2RGB`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d8/d01/group__imgproc__color__conversions.html#gga4e0972be5de079fed4e3a10e24ef5ef0ad3db9ff253b87d02efe4887b2f5d77ee)  mode is `4`.

Answer (score 2):

Because cv2 opens image in BGR mode. You need to use `cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)`