# How to convert numpy matrix to OpenCV image [python]

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I have a numpy 2d matrix which represents a colored image. This matrix has some negative and floating point numbers but of course I can display the image using imshow(my_matrix).

[image: my_matrix_screenshot]

I need to perform histogram equalization to this colored image so I found a code here in stackoverflow using OpenCV ([OpenCV Python equalizeHist colored image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31998428/opencv-python-equalizehist-colored-image)) but the problem is I am unable to convert the 2d matrix to OpenCV matrix which takes three channels for RGB.

I was searching again but all I found is to convert regular 3d numpy matrix to OpenCV matrix so how can numpy 2d matrix be converted to OpenCV matrix which has 3 channels?

Comment: What is the output of `my_matrix.shape`?

Comment: The output is (90, 100)

Comment: "I have a numpy 2d matrix which represents a colored image" If you know the original shape of this color image, you can use `np.reshape()` to convert this to a 3D array

Comment: `new_img = np.reshape(img,(rows,cols/3,3)`

Comment: It gives an error: ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 9000 into shape (90,33,3) in this line: new_img = np.reshape(new_img_tmp,(int(new_img_tmp.shape[0]), int(new_img_tmp.shape[1]/3),3))

Answer (score 10):

because the numpy.ndarray is the base of OpenCV, so you just write the code as usual,like

```
img_np = np.ones([100,100])
img_cv = cv2.resize(img_np,(200,200))
```

you can try

Comment: This answer seems to be answering an entirely different question. The question didn't ask about resizing an array.

Answer (score -3):

It is better to stack the existing numpy array one above the other of its own copy than to reshape it and add the third axis. 
Check this code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a = np.random.rand(90, 100) # Replace this line with your 90x100 numpy array.
a = np.expand_dims(a, axis = 2)
a = np.concatenate((a, a, a), axis = 2)
print(a.shape)
# (90, 100, 3)
plt.imshow(a)
plt.show()
```

You will get a gray colored image.

Comment: Thank you! but I get totally distracted image or you can say different image when I used the code above!

Comment: Hope you have not used `np.random.rand` line while running. You have to replace that line with your already existing 90x100 numpy array. I generated a random array just for the code completion sake.

Comment: of course not. I just plugged my matrix over there ;) but I got the weird result. I don't know if it is possible to send you the original image and the resulted image. here is what I am doing: a = new_img_tmp
a = np.expand_dims(a, axis = 2)
a = np.concatenate((a, a, a), axis = 2)
print(a.shape)
# (90, 100, 3)
plt.imshow(a)
plt.show()